# Conditional checkbox fields if checked show a related textfield

Tags: forms, entities

So I want to create an Order form for my products list in Drupal 7, I'm using [Entity form](http://drupal.org/project/entityform) module, I have a prepopulated checkbox list widget to show all my product's node title as checkbox. What I want is if anyone checks a checkbox a textfield shows up to add the amount he wants to offer. I tried [Conditional fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module too but it kind of doesn't work for my case because there will be more products added to the list and I cant add textfield to it manually and it will be a massive waste of time to do that.

I appreciate any suggestions and approaches or any other modules you might recommend.

Comment: Have you considered Field Collection field (as container) with Checkbox field and Text field?

Comment: Not yet, thanks for the hint though, I'll try it in couple of hours and let you know if it works, but I guess this isn't exactly what I want

Comment: well field collection doesn't do much relating to my issue

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70410/toggle-text-field-depending-on-checkbox-value-in-drupal-6 it will help you

Comment: even this too http://randyfay.com/content/ajax-example-textfields-driven-checkboxes

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bala, first one works if it was static byt Randy fay link looks promising, Im going to dig into it and let you know if it works

Comment: I can't think of a module or easy solution that does this. Perhaps though, you could [create your own field api type](http://clikfocus.com/blog/how-set-custom-field-type-using-drupal-7-fields-api) to do this though. You may want to look at the [fapi #states functionality](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example%21form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7) too. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to show a field when something gets checkked, you could just use JS to display a hidden field.

My approach would be to make custom table form that has the required input field as hidden. Then add javascript event listener to checkboxes that show the input at that row.

Then just do the normal validation and submit callbacks to update entities based on rows which are checked.